# vertx run FileName.java not working

Tags: vert.x

I am trying to run vertx programme. I am standing on the same folder the .java exist.

vertx run TestVerticle.java

```
Mar 24, 2017 7:19:27 PM io.vertx.core.Starter
SEVERE: Failed in deploying verticle
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestVerticle
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:42)
at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.createVerticles(DeploymentManager.java:184)
at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeployVerticle$2(DeploymentManager.java:157)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.checkCallHandler(FutureImpl.java:188)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:100)
at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:130)
at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:102)
at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:90)
at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:595)
at io.vertx.core.Starter.runVerticle(Starter.java:333)
at io.vertx.core.Starter.run(Starter.java:130)
at io.vertx.core.Starter.main(Starter.java:101)
```

I checked JAVA_HOME, CLASS_PATH ll properly set unable to find the reason. Please help. I have been struggling this from last two days without any success.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 from Digital Ocean

Answer (score 0):

Atlast before I go to sleep I curiously tried vertx run with --cp command and it worked !

vertx run -cp $CLASS_PATH TestVerticle.java (even though TestVerticle.java present in the current folder !)

which means that my CLASS_PATH or the current folder is not taken into consideration by default by vertx. Unfortunately I don't know why but atleast my server is now running.

Comment: This sound like an older version of Vert.x. Recent versions of Vert.x add the current directory to the classpath when running a source Java verticle.

Comment: No I am using 3.4.1 vertx .. Its not the problem in my MAC but I strangely found this in my Ubuntu 16.x Digital Ocean Server.